# CakePHP, How do I accept a parameter for a controller and not use an action?

Tags: php, cakephp

Would like http://websites.com/users/username1 URL structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app/config/routes.php file you could add:

`Router::connect('/users/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));`

This would route all requests to /users/ to the index action of the users controller.  If you want to use a different action, just replace 'index' with the action you prefer to use.

More info is here:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration